# How to consistently test AJAX using Arquillian Graphene?

Tags: ajax, firefox, junit, jboss-arquillian

I am running Arquillian Graphene (2.0.0.Alpha3) with WebDriver and I am getting inconsistent results.  At times, my JUnit test will pass without a problem and other times I will get errors like this:

```
12:13:29.667 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: ReferenceError: Graphene is not defined
Command duration or timeout: 946 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:18'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_30'
Session ID: 6dce0406-d50d-46d9-8e28-01f159a593b7
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=10.0.12, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:533)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:441)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:101)
    at $Proxy1.executeScript(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.executeScript(EventFiringWebDriver.java:209)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ExecuteScript.call(ExecuteScript.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ExecuteScript.call(ExecuteScript.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Seems like most of the problems occur with the request guard.  For example:

```
guardXhr(_acceptButton).click();
```

What could be the cause?  Is there a way to debug or workaround the issue?

Comment: Looks like this is a potential bug with Graphene: [ARQGRA-262](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQGRA-262)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confirmed to be a bug in 2.0.0.Alpha3: [ARQGRA-262](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQGRA-262).

A fix is available and seems to work using the latest 2.0.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT.